# How can we send device info using MFMailComposeViewCotroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've seen in some apps that when you click on a "Feedback" page it shows up an MFMailComposeViewController with some information in the message body like the device type and the iOS version written up already. This is sometimes useful to know when users are reporting problems so you know the device that is having problems.

Is this a built-in characteristic of objective-c or are there any external libraries which make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what you want from `UIDevice` class.

```
UIDevice *currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *model = [currentDevice model];
NSString *systemVersion = [currentDevice systemVersion];
```

See [article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-accessing-device-data-with-uidevice-and-nslocale--mobile-11511) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my question very clearly. Is there a way to add installation id?

Comment: What is installation id?

Comment: I researched on Google and found that what I was looking for (``uniqueIdentifier`` method) was deprecated since iOS 6.1.

Comment: You should generate UUID.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve though informations.

For iOS Version

```
NSString *iOSVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

for Device model you can write a function something like below
also you need to import `#import <sys/utsname.h>`

```
-(NSString *) deviceModelName{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    NSString *modelName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return modelName;
}
```